# Xamarin Forms/Android map app runs on emulator, but crashes on physical device

Tags: android, xamarin, opengl-es, arcgis

I'm trying to create a simple map app with the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Xamarin, with the Xamarin.Forms option, so far with just the Android version (don't have access to a Mac for iOS yet). I can run the app just fine on an emulator. But when I deploy it to my physical Android tablet (Nexus 7 w/5.0.1), the app crashes when it goes to display the map. I've even packaged it up and had a friend deploy it to their new Samsung phone and it also crashes there.

Code is extremely simple. Here's the entire main method in the shared code ContentPage class (the ArcGIS SDK only supports the shared code approach):

```
InitializeComponent ();

myMap = new Map(Basemap.CreateImagery());

// MyMapView is in the XAML markup
MyMapView.Map = myMap;
```

The app crashes with the "Unfortunately (app name) has stopped". In Visual Studio, the output includes this:

```
Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec

05-16 10:24:24.083 E/AndroidRuntime(24893): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1373
05-16 10:24:24.083 E/AndroidRuntime(24893): Process: ArcGisMapTest.Droid, PID: 24893
05-16 10:24:24.083 E/AndroidRuntime(24893): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
05-16 10:24:24.083 E/AndroidRuntime(24893): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:858)
05-16 10:24:24.083 E/AndroidRuntime(24893): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1023)
05-16 10:24:24.083 E/AndroidRuntime(24893): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1400)
05-16 10:24:24.083 E/AndroidRuntime(24893): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

Based on other online posts for the configSpec error message, this would seem to be an OpenGL issue. But the physical devices appear to support the required OpenGL ES 2.0. I'm also able to run a little app with the sample code at 
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.OpenGLView/

I've also run both the ESRI Xamarin.Forms samples and the Xamarin.Android samples on the emulator and devices, with the same result. Any ideas as to cause here?

Comment: In which device are you testing it? you state the device seems to support ogl 2.0 but without the model of the device it's not verifiable.

Comment: Local tablet is an Asus Nexus 7 (2012), now running 5.0.1. Also tested on an Asus Nexus 7 (2013) and a less-than-year-old Samsung phone (don't have the phone/model). My understanding is that Open GL ES 2.0 has been supported since Android 2.

Comment: It depends on the device, but hey, I use the exact same device (nexus 7 2013)  for debugging and I'm using right now the maps and ogl2... there is something really strange. try to remove from the .droid project the Xamarin.Forms.Maps package and the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps package, clean the solution, delete the bin and obj folders from the project, add again the packages and recompile again, somethimes with these strange bugs with Xamarin cleaning everything helps.

Comment: Note I'm not using the Android/Google Maps package (that tag was added to the thread by someone else, not me). Issue occurs with the Esri ArcGIS Xamarin SDK. Probably something specific to that package.

Comment: Oh, ok, then try to use the nolinker with that package, itsyour best bet then, the Xamarin packages already are protected from linking (the needed parts) but that package may have something which needs to not be linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an opengl error then perhaps check developer options on the device and make sure opengl 2.0 is enabled there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I don't see anything specific about OpenGL in the developer options on the device, other than "Enable OpenGL traces", which I've set to Logcat but haven't found anything useful from that. I've tried the "Force GPU rendering" option with no success.

Comment: I eventually bought a new Android tablet and the (slightly newer version) Esri API works on it. I'll conclude that either the old Asus Nexus 7 2012 doesn't support OpenGL ES 2, or something wasn't configured right, either on device or in the API or package.